# How does time travel really work in The Terminator Universe

Tags: time-travel, the-terminator-series

> There are two separate veins of time-travel/causality theories.
>
> 1. A new timeline branches off when one goes back in time (not "going back in time" as much as simply going to a different alternate
>      universe/timeline where conditions are identical to how things were at
>      the target point. See: Dragon Ball Z).
> 2. Causality is absolute, and there is a single timeline. any changes made to the past have already occurred, and thus are not
>      "changes". They're simply events on the (immutable) timeline. Once
>      something has been experienced, it is frozen and will always happen.

*Directly copied from [acolyte's](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/7189/) answer in [Was Kyle Reese always John Connor's father?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40529/was-kyle-reese-always-john-connors-father)

So how does time travel really work in The Terminator Universe? (I'm talking about the movies, but If someone has information about how it works in SCC it's ok).

For example, in **T1**, we could say that they follow the second one, but in **T2**, we learn that the events in **T1** did changed the future (first theory) because of the arm and chip of the first Terminator SkyNet technology was improved, BUT then in the same movie, Sarah, John and Uncle Bob destroyed Cyberdyne facility, and nothing happened, the liquid terminator is still there in the timeline, but ultimately they did push back judgement day. So they did changed the future.

Also in **T4** John is surprised that SkyNet developed better terminators faster than in the original timeline.

**EDIT:**

This is also relevant: [Why did future John Connor bother to send the T-101 Terminator back?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39617/why-did-future-john-connor-bother-to-send-the-t-101-terminator-back?rq=1)

The most upvoted answer states:

> The point is that time travel movies, by their very nature, have plot
>   holes like this related to time-travel paradoxes. We, as the audience,
>   just need to go with the flow, and take such things as a grain of
>   salt.

So is time travel in Terminator inherently inconsistent and we just have to accept that it is the way it is? (My jerk brain is bothering me with this, but he is totally ok with the fact that [Cyclops eyes are doors to another dimension](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24723/is-the-red-beam-coming-out-of-cyclops-eye-a-laser-beam?rq=1))

Comment: Related: [Nude time travel in Terminator Universe](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4752/nude-time-travel-in-terminator-universe).

Comment: By the by, if you include the comics, the *Robocop vs. Terminator* comic also includes the idea that time changes in waves slower than the speed of light, giving the computers a chance to adjust their tactics as they perceive changes happening further away.

Comment: Very well, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I was having a conversation about this today, how cool is that?

I believe that, in the T1 movie they of course change the future, not enough to prevent war, but to change how machines are built (technology from the future trapped in past used to build better machines) so that's why we see how in T2 movie the Terminator is way better and evolved than T-400.

So, now we have 2 future time lines. The first one is rewrited to a second one, with more "evolved technology " but with the same "conclution", war, because IA machines get build anyways.

I wouldn't pay much attention to T3 and T4 movies...there are too many gaps in the temporal time lines, and in my opinion it makes all confusing.

P.S = sorry about my grammatical english, I'm kind of rusty :S

I'll edit my question, because [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40542/what-stops-skynet-from-just-sending-later-cyborgs-back-to-the-same-time-they-sen) are explaning how this "time travel" works. :D

Answer (score 0):

First, there is clearly at least a third "vein" of time-travel/causality theories other than the two mentioned, which seems to be the usual vein of time-travel sci-fi:

3) There is one time-line, but time travelers can change the timeline by going back and changing events from what had occurred before they travel back. Doing so makes the previously-established timeline exist only in the memories and stories of the time travelers.

This is not the same as vein 1 mentioned in your question, because if that were the case, then time travel would just be a way to vacation and/or escape to new possibilities for yourself, without causing any change in the timeline you left except for your own absence from it. Well, I suppose it also creates a timeline where the future would be different, but it doesn't say that the timeline you left will be affected, unless you can return to that timeline, and bring with you some knowledge or artifact that would be helpful. In other words, if Skynet thought cause and effect worked like vein 1, it wouldn't expect anything it sends back to affect its own state. It might instead *send itself back* and happily conquer that new timeline from that point on.

But it doesn't do that. Skynet, and the humans, act as if it is the usual vein 3 I describe above, where a computer in 2500 can send a robot back to 1985 and change its own situation in 2500... as if there is one thread of cause and effect, and backwards time travel causes all history to be re-written from the point the traveler arrives in the past, forward.

This creates two types of timeline. One is the "current state of the timeline" but it and its shape are different at each point along the larger cause-and-effect timeline. I.e., you have a timeline that goes from 0 till the first reverse time traveler, then it hops back to whenever he went back to, then it falls forward in time until the next time traveler in that timeline, then the cause and effect falls forward from that point, etc.

That would be easy enough to track, except what we also have in Terminator and many other time travel stories, is multiple travelers from the future coming back to struggle with each other about what will happen next, which means that apparently the effect of sending something back doesn't have immediate and exclusive effects on the future somehow.

Further muddying everything in Terminator, of course, is the seeming paradox of post-apocalypse John Conner sending his adult friend back to pre-apocalypse times save his mother and ending up fathering himself. It seems to me that's not necessarily a paradox, if the John Conner on the first timeline was fathered by someone else, leading to a father upgrade to future war veteran in T1, which led to that John Conner to send back a Terminator to protect and raise him in T2 (father upgrade #2)... But that would be undermined by the photograph shown in a memory of John's Father in the original timeline future war, supposedly given to him but taken at the end of T1.

So there is what the characters think about how cause and effect works, and how it might actually be working, which is left as a kind of teasing uncertain question... unless/until the point that audiences start to suspect that the people making the films don't actually think these things through with a focus on having them make actual sense, and are much more focused on dramatic effect.

Answer (score -1):

I've recently studied The Terminator live-action universe (currently 6 theatrical films and 2 television seasons) very carefully. I can answer any question you have.  Here is how the time-travel works:

Whenever someone goes back in time, they go to a copy of the original timeline.  The original timeline is the timeline where no one arrives from the future.  The original timeline has time-travel being invented and EVERYONE that goes back in time, from that original timeline, goes to a copy of that original timeline that can thusly be changed by time-travelers from that original timeline.  We'll call this new timeline 'Timeline 2'.

In 'Timeline 2', it differentiates from the original timeline because of the time-travelers from that original timeline now affecting and shaping this new timeline.

In 'Timeline 2', when time-travel is invented, the ones that go back in time from 'Timeline 2', will ALL go to 'Timeline 3'.   Everyone that goes back in time from 'Timeline 3' will ALL go to 'Timeline 4'.

Every timeline starts out as a copy of the Original Timeline, until time-travelers, from a sort of parallel future, arrive to change it.

The only seeming exception is the time-travel in Terminator: Dark Fate.  It seems that in this scenario, a new form of time-travel is invented.  It can be assumed that the time-travel throughout the series is invented by Skynet and/or The Resistance.  But in Dark Fate, there is a future where Legion takes over and perhaps Legion creates a new form of time-travel that actually lets someone go to their own past or a copy of their own past THAT IS NOT the original timeline.  Or rather, we could say, the timeline they are in is now, perhaps, the new (their own) original timeline.  The point is that this is a new kind of time-travel.

In all previous films and television series, every time-traveler that arrived in a timeline was from the same timeline they left from.  That's why you never saw two of the same characters/individuals arriving as a time-traveler.  You never see two of Kyle Reese arriving from the future. Only one.  And every time-traveler from "the future" shares that same "future" with all the other time-travelers.

But, in Dark Fate, we see an agent of Skynet ('Carl') and an agent of Legion (the terminator that can split itself into two), two terminators from different futures, arriving in the same timeline.

Comment: This isn't the case in Genisys, either.

Comment: @Valorum  Elaborate.  What is not the case in Genisys?

Comment: In Genisys we see that there's a single timestream that can be altered, Butterfly Effect-style.

Comment: @Valorum  I haven't seen The Butterfly Effect, so I can't comment on that comparison. Though I kinda get what you mean.              ... I want to preface by saying that movies are art and meant to be interpreted by the individual, so you can interpret anything anyway you like (I won't say 'you're wrong'). I will explain how I see it and why I see it that way.          So, you're referring to Kyle's visions of different timelines while in the 'nexus point'.       (Continued...)

Comment: @Valorum Kyle experiences different timelines/memories as he slips back into time.  I just see this as how time-travel kinda works in that you can glimpse and FEEL yourself through time.  Kyle is going to a new timeline, to 1984 in that new timeline, where things will happen differently from what he experienced. The T-101 already went through, that means this new timeline (a copy of the original) is now changed.  (Continued...)

Comment: @Valorum And also, now that Skynet has ambushed John Connor right in front of Kyle, there are at least two more time-travelers that will now be arriving BEFORE Kyle arrives, therefore the timeline will now change AGAIN.  So this new timeline Kyle is going to is changing before he even arrives there (in the sense that it was going to be happening in one way, but now, with more time-travelers arriving before him, a different way) . As he's slipping back through time, he shares the new memories/life of his other self which conflict with his own personal memories growing up.

Comment: Indeed. Which is entirely inconsistent with the time travel seen in earlier films (film 1 = closed loop, film 2 = multiple timelines, Genisys = who the heck knows.

Comment: @Valorum    So, Kyle is somehow experiencing these new memories of his other self as he goes back in time.  Think of it like a string of unique code (your DNA, the person that makes up you) and now that he is going into a timeline where that code already exists, he glimpses that same DNA's place in time.  Kind of like how a computer will ask if you want to replace same file or keep both when it detects identical file-code. Then it adds a number to the code.  Kyle is merely seeing the results of the timeline (through his other near identical code) he is going to.

Comment: @Valorum Kyle is picked up out of his timeline in 2029, then descended down into next new timeline (2029) then whisked back in time to 1984 in this new timeline.

Comment: @Valorum Film 1 is not a closed loop (in my interpretation).  There was an original timeline where Sarah Connor has sex with some guy, births John Connor, Skynet destroys the world on some unknown (to us) date, then John Connor leads the resistance. Skynet uses time-travel to send itself back via the T-101's chip, and kill John's mother to win in a new timeline. John Connor sends his best guy, Kyle Reese, to intercept.  Timeline 2 (the first new timeline) is where Kyle Reese has sex with Sarah, she births a kid she was already told to name John Connor. Skynet speeds up Judgment Day to 1997.

Comment: @Valorum (Still in Timeline 2) John Connor, with foreknowledge thanks to Kyle Reese and his mother, leads resistance. Skynet is smarter because it's developed from itself (the T-101 chip), it retains information through timelines this way. Again, sending itself back in time to recreate what it knows lead to its new existence.  This is where we pick up in Timeline 3 (The Terminator) and it appears to be a paradox loop, but it's merely a seeming temporary loop.  Skynet goes through time this way, through that T-101 chip. Even after T2 where John and Sarah destroy chip, it was already backed up.

Comment: @Valorum We see Dyson back it up in T2.  So it lives on. And the result is Skynet in Genisys (played by Matt Smith).  Then it appears (just a theory) that Skynet starts fighting itself (two iterations of Skynet, old and new) by Skynet helping Sarah and Kyle by sending Pops. But now I'm getting into possible theories that I don't necessarily hold onto, but I think about the possibilities (of who sent Pops back?  who sent the T-1000 back, in Genisys?).