# Why did Skynet not use a T1000 again in Terminator 3?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-3-rise-of-the-machines

Ok, All of us saw the overwhelming power of the T-1000, and the lucky way that the heroes used to destroy him... why not send another one? just with two clear instructions "kill John Connor and stay away from a foundry"

Comment: You're assuming that the fate of the T1000 (foundry event) was somehow communicated to the future Skynet.  Anything you can provide to back that up ?

Comment: Trying to make sense out of the terminator timeline is just an exercise in futility. Really. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40560/how-does-time-travel-really-work-in-the-terminator-universe

Comment: Why are we assuming that the terminator sent back during T3 was sent back after the terminator in T2?  This is time travel after all.  Perhaps the T3 terminator was sent back before the T2 terminator?  I haven't watched them in a while, but I don't recall anything specifically defining what order they were sent back.

Comment: Im agree, there is not any clue that allow skynet to know about the events in T2, is a matter of apreciation, for me T1000 was more powerful.

Answer (score 3):

At this point Skynet appears to know that John Connor is sending back terminators to protect himself (and others). On the T-X:

> **John Connor:** So... she's an anti-Terminator Terminator? You've got to be [expletive] me.
>   **Terminator:** No, I am not [expletive] you.

A T-1000 failed against a T-800. So Skynet has decided to send a T-X. The T-X is special because it brought back a number of futuristic weapons it can use underneath its liquid metal exterior.

Comment: Maybe if we think as a AI could be correct, IF T-1000 FAILED THEN USE T-X , its a very "binary" answer.